# Receiving webhooks from stripe to wix

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, velo

Hello everyone I am trying to send json data from a completed checkout to my six website via webhook I need to retrieve the order number and the product that the customer have bought but I cannot figure out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are listening to the `checkout.session.completed` events. In your webhook event handling code, you can [expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects?lang=curl#expanding_objects) the `line_item.data.price` [hash](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=curl#checkout_session_object-line_items-data-price-id) of the `CheckoutSession` object to get the price/product info.

I'm not sure about the order number that you refer to, perhaps you mean the [payment_intent](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object?lang=curl#checkout_session_object-payment_intent)?